# moodle.sty character encoding problem

Tags: moodle

I am using [moodle.sty](https://ctan.org/pkg/moodle) to prepare a moodle quiz. My questions are in german and I have a problem with special german characters: No matter what encoding I use in the TeX file (tex-style "a, etc/utf8/latin9) the XML file created by moodle.sty will always claim

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

but contain Latin-9 encoded characters. Below is sample file showing the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,ngerman]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{babel}

\usepackage{moodle}

\begin{document}

\begin{quiz}{Testquiz}

\begin{multi}{Testfrage}
 Was könnte die Ableitung von $x^3$ sein?
\item* $3x^2$
\item  $\frac{1}{4} x^4+C$
\item $51$
\end{multi}

\end{quiz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just found another workaround: full tex-style encoding: \"a instead of "a also works. This will put &auml; into the xml file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution (workaround?) I use is:

1. remove the `fontenc`, `babel` and `inputenc` packages;
2. use `lualatex` to compile

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{moodle}

\begin{document}

\begin{quiz}{Testquiz}

\begin{multi}{Testfrage}
 Was könnte die Ableitung von $x^3$ sein?
\item* $3x^2$
\item  $\frac{1}{4} x^4+C$
\item $51$
\end{multi}

\end{quiz}

\end{document}
```

works and produces

[image]

Comment: Indeed, using lualatex seems to fix this (and some other issues as well). Thanks!

Comment: Just for the record: Removing babel does not seem to be necessary. I need it to get correct hyphenation rules.

Comment: @gerald my experience is that the hyphenation is transformed in hard hyphens in the Moodle page, so I had to disable it...

Comment: But the hyphenation only pertains to the pdf output? Of course the students will never see this, but it makes it easier to read for me.

Comment: You got me here --- I should check, but the problem I think it was that the `\discretionaryhyphen` inserted messed up the moodle output. Could be that the `lualatex` version uses the Unicode one, and so all is fine. Just check...